# Android Log In with Gmail not supported

Tags: java, android, authentication, gmail

I 'm developing an Android application that allows the user to login to Gmail . The problem I have is that by integrating this is cycled by clicking on the LOG IN button. Here the code I use , any idea why this happens, or any example I can use?

public class AndroidGooglePlusExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

// Google client to communicate with Google
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private boolean mIntentInProgress;
private boolean signedInUser;
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
private SignInButton signinButton;
private ImageView image;
private TextView username, emailLabel;
private LinearLayout profileFrame, signinFrame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signinButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signin);
    signinButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    emailLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

    profileFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.profileFrame);
    signinFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.signinFrame);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();


}


protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // store mConnectionResult
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (signedInUser) {
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case RC_SIGN_IN:
        if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            signedInUser = false;

        }
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    signedInUser = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getProfileInformation();
}

private void updateProfile(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        signinFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        profileFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        signinFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        profileFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            username.setText(personName);
            emailLabel.setText(email);

            new LoadProfileImage(image).execute(personPhotoUrl);

            // update profile frame with new info about Google Account
            // profile
            updateProfile(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    updateProfile(false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.signin:
        googlePlusLogin();
        break;
    }
}

public void signIn(View v) {
    googlePlusLogin();
}

public void logout(View v) {
    googlePlusLogout();
}

private void googlePlusLogin() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        signedInUser = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

private void googlePlusLogout() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateProfile(false);
    }
}

// download Google Account profile image, to complete profile
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView downloadedImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView image) {
        this.downloadedImage = image;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap icon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return icon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        downloadedImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: How do you mean? Can you explain/elaborate on this : 'The problem I have is that by integrating this is cycled by clicking on the LOG IN button.' ?

Comment: The project runs properly, but when I click on the Log In button is cycled and displays a TOAST that says " An internal error occurred "
And the device screen flashes , ( turns on and off ). 

Maybe it's the APIS as this project has the API 5.01, 
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: Have you filled up the details in the consent screen and credentials for your project in the google api console?